# C# program crash

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get my first ever C# application working as intended. :)

This application is a time converter, which allows user to input numbers into six different text boxes. For example, user puts 2009 into yyyy.Text, 20 into dd.Text, 02 into M.text, 02 into hh.Text, 49 into mm.Text and 35 into ss.Text. Then the program converts the numbers into a hexadecimal string.

For example,
2009 20 02 02:49:35 -> 63370694975000000 -> E1234FB3278DC0

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String dateString = yyyy.Text + dd.Text + M.Text + hh.Text + mm.Text + ss.Text;
            DateTime timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy dd M  hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            long ticks = timestamp.Ticks;
            long microseconds = ticks / 10;
            convertedText.Text = microseconds.ToString("X");
        }
```

The application is compiled fine, but after putting numbers into the text boxes and clicking the 'Convert' button, the program crashes. The error: Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Am I using the wrong DataTime format? or something? :(

Thanks in advance... I wanna get this working :)

Comment: shouldn't yyyy dd M  hh:mm:ss be yyyy dd MM hh:mm:ss?

Comment: "C# program crash" blame windows! - Can you please be more explicit in future questions?

Comment: I think your problem is a lack of spaces, but you might also consider using DateTime.TryParse to make your application more robust.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need spaces and colons as you declare in the format.

Answer (score 2):

When making the `dateString`, don't forget to insert spaces.
Use

```
String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}:{4}:{5}",yyyy.Text, dd.Text, M.Text, hh.Text, mm.Text, ss.Text)
```

And, place a try-catch block - it's the easiest way to catch exceptions when converting, (although not recommended for a good program), in case the user inputs some insane numbers and text.

Answer (score 1):

Your **dateString** does not correspond to the format you specified - you have a string without any separators (like spaces or colons). Format the string accordingly to your format. Also, it is always a good idea to use format utils. But I think you should use string, not String:

```
string dateString = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}:{4}:{5}",
    yyyy.Text, dd.Text, M.Text, hh.Text, mm.Text, ss.Text);
```

Comment: I agree with the format suggestion.  String vs string isn't an issue.  Since 2.0 (I believe) the compiler replaces String with string.  There's no longer a String class with any functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert a breakpoint on the DateTime timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy dd M  hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) line.

Then before you execute that command, hover your mouse over `dateString`. Then I think you will see that dateString does nto match the format you have provided to ParseExact at all.

When the string matches the format you have given, it should work fine.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Solution 1:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   DateTime timestamp = new DateTime( 
                                Convert.ToInt32(yyyy.Text) 
                                , Convert.ToInt32(M.Text) 
                                , Convert.ToInt32(dd.Text) 
                                , Convert.ToInt32(hh.Text) 
                                , Convert.ToInt32(mm.Text) 
                                , Convert.ToInt32(ss.Text)); 

    long ticks = timestamp.Ticks; 
    long microseconds = ticks / 10; 
    convertedText.Text = microseconds.ToString("X"); 
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 

string dateString = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2} {3}:{4}:{5}", M.Text,dd.Text,yyyy.Text, hh.Text, mm.Text, ss.Text); 
long ticks = Convert.ToDateTime(dateString).Ticks;
long microseconds = ticks / 10;
convertedText.Text = microseconds.ToString("X");        
}
```

**Output:**

```
E1234FB3278DC0
```